# Smarty assign value to an array variable index

Tags: php, smarty

I am using SMARTY and I need to create an array and assign value to a particular index of it.

Something like:

```
{foreach from=$a key='i' item='b'}
//Some calculations here giving me a VALUE
ARRAY[$i] = $VALUE;
{/foreach}
```

Now the problem is when I am using standard Smarty Assign syntax

```
{assign var='array.$i' value=$VALUE}
{assign var='array[$i]' value=$VALUE}
{assign var=$array.$i value=$VALUE}
{assign var='$array[$i]' value=$VALUE}
```

its not working. I need to use this array later in the code and hence need it in an array format only

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried the [assign shorthand](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.builtin.functions.tpl#language.function.shortform.assign) instead?

```
{$array.$i = $VALUE}
```